# Cannot get JSTL tags to work with Tomcat 9

Tags: jsp, tomcat, jstl

I'm using tomcat 9 and I can't get JSTL tags to work. I tried every solution out there and nothing seems to work. I'm on the verge of giving up my 3 months long JSP studies because of this. Nothing I tried makes it work.

I am not sure what is causing this. I'm not sure which versions of JSTL and web.xml are compatible with Tomcat 9. I am not using maven.

**EDIT:**

I finally was able to resolve the functionality of JSTL tags in my result.jsp file by downloading and adding into my WEB-INF/lib folder the latest jstl-1.2.jar. So I was able to make the standard forEach tag work but I am not able to receive my array from the servlet. I suspect it has something to do with my web.xml version specifications, I am using Tomcat 7 and jstl-1.2.

What would be the appropriate web.xml configurations in my case?

I get this error

Type Exception Report

Message The absolute uri: [http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core] cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: [http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core] cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:54)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:294)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:81)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.generateTldResourcePath(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:251)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:122)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:435)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:493)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1450)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:144)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:244)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:105)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:206)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:391)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:367)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:351)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:605)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:399)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:379)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:327)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)

Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

My Servlet:

```java
package com;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MovieList extends HttpServlet {
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)throws IOException,ServletException{
        String [] movieList = {"movie 1","movie 2","movie 3"};
        request.setAttribute("movieList", movieList);

        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("result.jsp");
        view.forward(request,response);
    }
}
```

My web.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="4.0" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
   http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd">

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Tester</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Tester</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Tester</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Tester</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>



</web-app>
```

My View

```
 <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
<table>
    <c:forEach items="${movieList}" var="movie">
        <td><c:out value="${movie}"/></td>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>nexnau</groupId>
  <artifactId>makaroni</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>makaroni Maven Webapp</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->

  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl/jstl -->


  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>makaroni</finalName>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

**I get this result**

[image]

**This is what I get with the servlet**

[image]

[My environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c07ai.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I highly doubt you miss this at the top of jsp file:

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
```

Second, I think you need to change the servlet from "doPost" to "doGet"

If it still can not work, I did a demo for you, I hope you know maven and git

```
https://github.com/632691987/demo1.git
```

If you still still don't understand, leave me a message by following link:

```
https://github.com/632691987/demo1/issues/new
```

Finally, I want to give a joke: 19 years ago, When I first learn "for" in C language, I wanted to give up, because I don't understand! :)

Now, I was a programmer for 15 years!

Comment: I'm not using Maven, I tried your method, it didnt work. It only works without the servlet, just the forEach tag with start="" and end="". Thank you

Comment: It just doesn't want to communicate with the servlet. I tried everything. I did use the doGet() instead the doPost() and its still not working.

Comment: well, @EL , you should aware, your source code success or not, depends on your whole project every files, not only above 3 files. So you should check your whole project. You should learn how to use Maven, it is very easy. After you learn it, you would able to work about my source code! Come on, don't give up!

Comment: Well, buddy, I don't know your life, or your detail situation. Everyone has his choice, but since a guy like me, 38 year old, I can tell you that, to be in technology industry, is the fastest way (only way) can make one person among the middle class(from the bottom), especially when you are in developed country. You just lack someone guide you hand in hand. No matter what, you have tried! Good luck :) @EL

Comment: What do you mean file?

Comment: I added all the dependencies in the pom file and its still not working this is ridiculous,I'm still trying to get this to work all these days. this is so frustrating, I tried everything, maybe its just outdated? Should i move on to a different technology? The JSTL tags work without the servlet but not with the servlet, there is issues with the jstl and servlet communication i think

Comment: please see my pom.xml file i updated in the question.

Comment: hey @EL, your pom.xml file is not enough, I think you could completely copy my all files, and then in your project folder, command ```mvn clean install jetty:run```, then is ok, please don't try to create any file and edit any files by yourself at the moment, because you are not able to do it at the moment.

Comment: Yes, the technology you are using now, is 20 years ago. This is not a joke. Well, I don't know why you want to learn program, and what you are going to do. But if you want to make a living, you need accept a formal training to start up as a tester (yes, this is the easiest way to do), then find a company would accept a complete rookie(I know that is not easy to find, it depends on which country you are living) @EL

Comment: One more thing, don't listen to the guy told you redirect to another page and use what latest jar package. Yes, they are correct. But, that would make you more confuse. Don't do that, my way would more simple. Because I use what you use, and I make it. @EL

Comment: Didn't work. I downloaded your package from GitHub, and it didn't work. I really appreciate your help. I decided to move on Python/Django. Cheers!!!

Comment: @ Vincent - want to make money?

Comment: @ Vincent- If I pay you cloud you get this thing to work? This is just stupid. I fee like JSP just hates me, like it doesn't want to work for me, I tried everything.

Comment: hi @EL, sorry that long time no come here. Let me tell you, what I already give you, in github, the source code already work, but it doesn't work on your enviornment there, it means your working envionment has something wrong.

Comment: if you still can not make it, tell me, we can have a talk in zoom, I will assist you. But I want to tell you one thing: the technology you are working on is very old, no worth to spending time on it, no matter for your study or work @EL

Comment: If you want, send me a mail on vincentgwzhangbackup05@gmail.com.  But one more thing, No talk about money, we run open source sprint here, unless you tell me your source code running on business. @EL